# Category as a Horizontal menu in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Hai,

I have some parent catogories and sub categories in wordpress. I would like to have parent catogory as a main horizontal menu and sub menu as a sub category of that specific parent catogory. Both main menu and submenu should be in the horizontal structure. So on mouse over of the main menu will show the submenu. could u guys help me in this

thanks

Comment: Yeah!

I am also looking for this stuff also. I am running a [du hoc uc][1] site and tired of vertical sub-menu. Is there any kindly help?


  [1]: http://thongtinduhocuc.com

Answer (score 1):

Theres an [article in Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Horizontal_Menus) I used a while ago to help a friend.